# Selenium 2.0 - @FindBy - Dropdown List selection

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to find drop-down list on webpage. Help to locate it and create the method for it.
Following is the code -

```
<select name="equipment_type" class="smalltext0" onchange="return submitByFormNameAndAction('featureAddChangeForm','FeatureAddChangeValidateMobile.do')">
 <option class="device" selected="" value="P">iPhone</option>
 <option class="device" value="Z">Blackberry</option>
 <option class="device" value="3">Android</option>
</select>*
```

Comment: Seriously, use internet next time. -1

http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/1355/what-is-the-correct-way-to-select-an-option-using-seleniums-python-webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Previous Answer + new stuff:

```
@Findby(css = "#id")
private Webelement selectElement;

public Select getPageSelectElement(){
  return new Select(selectElement);
}
```

Would be cool if we could get it directly from PageFactory though.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this in your PageFactory:

```
@FindBy(how = How.NAME, using = "equipment_type")
WebElement selectElement

...

Select getPageSelectElement(){
    return new Select(selectElement);
}
```

You can then use the getPageSelectElement function to return a Select object from your page factory that can be used in your test.

Please note that the above is not code for a full page factory, just the bits you need to add to your page factory to find and return the Select element.